# how to animate a parent without the child's animation

Tags: html, css

I would lkie to animate a parent without the child's animation.

My HTML & CSS structure looks like this:

```css
.parent{
   background-image: url('https://pm1.narvii.com/6195/421ddbf8c9a2fb1715ef833f869164dc1beb8600_hq.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 35px;
    margin: 15px 0;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.parent:hover{
    animation-name: bounce;
 }
 
 @keyframes bounce {
    0%, 100%, 20%, 50%, 80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform:     translateY(0);
        transform:         translateY(0)
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        -ms-transform:     translateY(-30px);
        transform:         translateY(-30px)
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
        -ms-transform:     translateY(-15px);
        transform:         translateY(-15px)
    }
}

p{
  font-size: 50px;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>TEST</p>
</div>
```

Finally, I'd like the text inside to be 'static'. My point is, the text inside the parent shouldn't move during the animation. I just want the image to move, not the text

Comment: Animate `background-position` rather than translating the whole element.

Comment: @Quasipickle How to anime background-position

Answer (score 0):

Put the image and the text in the same container.Then set the text out of the flow with absolute.z index is so the text dosn't disappaire when animation starts.Put the text first so you can use + to make the image bounce when hovering on the text.
transform and left for centering the text.

```css
.image{
    background-image: url('https://pm1.narvii.com/6195/421ddbf8c9a2fb1715ef833f869164dc1beb8600_hq.jpg');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
     padding: 35px;
     margin: 15px 0;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-fill-mode: both;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
     animation-iteration-count: infinite;     
 }
 #parent{     
    position:relative  
     
 }
 #pid{  
     transform: translateY(50%);   
     position:absolute;
     z-index:1;     
     left:50%;
     
 }

 .image:hover,#pid:hover + .image{
     animation-name: bounce;
  }
  
  @keyframes bounce {
     0%, 100%, 20%, 50%, 80% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
         -ms-transform:     translateY(0);
         transform:         translateY(0)
     }
     40% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
         -ms-transform:     translateY(-30px);
         transform:         translateY(-30px)
     }
     60% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
         -ms-transform:     translateY(-15px);
         transform:         translateY(-15px)
     }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title id="title">Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
        <div id=parent> 
            <p id="pid">TEST</p>
            <div class="image"></div>            
        </div>
    
   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you to add the snippet of the question and edit it to make it showed the fix

Comment: Sorry had to figure out how to do that.I think it worked out .It is better indeed ceaus i forgot to mention something els that you can see here.First time i help :).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can animate [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) which will only affect the bg image and not the text. I have also used [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) function, to keep the image centered while moving it up and down.

```css
.parent {
  background-image: url('https://pm1.narvii.com/6195/421ddbf8c9a2fb1715ef833f869164dc1beb8600_hq.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 35px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.parent:hover {
  animation-name: bounce;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  100%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80% {
    background-position: left 50% top 50%;
  }
  40% {
    background-position: left 50% top calc(50% + -30px);
  }
  60% {
    background-position: left 50% top calc(50% + -15px);
  }
}

p {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>TEST</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @LiOne Please check this out.